# Mean of $k$ highest out of $n$ i.i.d. draws from unit uniform distribution

Tags: probability, statistics

I am stuck with the following question:

There is a random variable $x\sim U[0,1] $. There are $n$ different draws (i.i.d.) being made. I am trying to compute the expected value/arithmetic mean of the $k$ highest of these draws.

That is, if I sort the draws $x_1\geq x_2\geq ...\geq x_n$, I am trying to compute $E[\frac{1}{k}\sum_{i=1}^kx_i]$.

While I have found [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1242841/what-is-the-expected-value-of-the-highest-of-n-independent-draws-from-the-unit-u) question on the expected value of the *highest* draw, I am unable to extend this to the average of the $k$ highes ones.

Comment: Standard fact that the highest has mean $\frac{n}{n+1}$, second highest has mean $\frac{n-1}{n+1}$, and so on. Add up, divide by $k$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add an $(n+1)$-th draw. Glue the ends of the interval together to form a circle, and cut the circle at the location of the $(n+1)$-th draw to form an interval again. The remaining $n$ draws are independently uniformly distributed on that interval. By symmetry, the $n+1$ segments between the $n+1$ draws all have the same expected length. Thus the expected value of $x_i$ is $1-\frac i{n+1}$, and the average you want is

$$
\frac1k\sum_{i=1}^k\left(1-\frac i{n+1}\right)=1-\frac{k+1}{2(n+1)}\;.
$$