Bound on the expectation of the maximum of a sequence, given bounds on the expected value of each element.
I have a sequence of independent random variables $U_1, U_2, \dots,U_N$.
Suppose $\mathbb{E}[U_i] \leq 1$ for all $i=1,\dots,N$, and let:
$$M_N = \max_{i=1,\dots,N} U_i$$
It is easy to see that $\mathbb{E}[U_i] \leq N$.
My questions are:

Is there a general tighter upper bound on the expectation of $M_N$?
If the answer is negative, what do I need from the $U_i$ to have a tighter bound?

For instance, if the $U_i$ are Gaussian with mean $\mu_i$ and variance $\sigma$, I can use the ideas here to get the bound:
$$\mathbb{E}[M_N] \leq \bar{\mu} + \sigma\sqrt{2\log(N)},$$
where $\bar{\mu} = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N \mu_i$.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3305117/expectation-of-maximum-of-n-i-i-d-random-variables
